# How to statistically test the predictability of evolution?

Tags: evolution, natural-selection, mutations, statistics, experimental-design

Can anyone recommend me an experimental study which tries to test the **predictability** of evolution? The closest works I found are the studies of fluctuation tests (f.e. classical study of Luria & Delbrück, 1943) which demonstrates that in bacteria, **genetic mutations arise in the absence of selection, rather than being a response to selection**. Is there any **other point of view** from which the predictability of evolution can be studied?

> Luria & Delbrück (1943) Mutations of bacteria from virus
>   sensitivity to virus resistance. *Genetics* **28**: 491–511.

Comment: What does "*intentionally occuring mutations*" even mean?

Comment: Hi @fileunderwater! Thank you for your comment. My question has been rephrased for better clarity.

Comment: There are things we are good at predicting and things we are not good at. Predictability of evolution is too a vast subject. You should refine it to a specific evolutionary process.

Comment: Are you interested in determining our predicitve power of a given evolutionary process or in demonstrating that mutations don't occur in response but is a (mainly) independent process? I think I don't fully understand your question.

Comment: Thank you @Remi.b for your comments. The reason for this question is that laymens often ask whether the "evolution has some final goal" (and then stops). I was just wondering, if such question could be tested by some simple experiment (simple enough for approx. 12 years old kids).

Comment: The issue with this kind of statement is that it is poorly defined and it is hard to know what experience would be considered as a good contradiction. I suppose that if you consider any experimental evolution experiment that has some replicates, you can show that they all end up a little (or completely) different. A famous example is the one of citrate usage in E. col by Lenski. Among hundreds of lines only one evolved the ability to synthetize citrate (after more than 30,000 generations)

Comment: You can consider mutation accumulation experiment showing that different mutations accumulate in different lines that are subject to the same conditions. You also may want to consider short term evolution showing the effect of genetic drift on allele frequencies. There are hundreds of study who would more or less address but the statement is too uncear to understand which one is of interest.

Comment: Predictable Evolution Trumps Randomness of Mutations
http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/predictable-evolution-trumps-randomness-of-mutations/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Lenski's evolutionary long-term experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._coli_long-term_evolution_experiment) should be a good example, without being familiar with Luria & Delbrück (1943). There they use replicated populations of E-coli to study (among other things) the "repeatability" (historical contingency) of evolutionary changes. Nice overviews of the project are given in [Blount et al. (2008)](http://www.pnas.org/content/105/23/7899.abstract) and [Philippe et al (2008)](http://jb.asm.org/content/191/3/909.long), where they study to what extent certain mutations are repeated in replicate populations, in relation to citrate metabolism and size/shape.

References:

- [Blount, Borland & Lenski. 2008. *Historical contingency and the evolution of a key innovation in an experimental population of Escherichia coli*. PNAS vol. 105 no. 23](http://www.pnas.org/content/105/23/7899.abstract)
- [Philippe et al (2008). *Evolution of Penicillin-Binding Protein 2 Concentration and Cell Shape during a Long-Term Experiment with Escherichia coli*. Journal of Bacteriology 191(3):909-21](http://jb.asm.org/content/191/3/909.long)

Comment: I second this.  I think with a Galaxy account, you could do the alignments and SNP calling yourself, if you so desired.